# SAPUI5 - how to set value to input parameter in binding dynamically

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana-xs

In my XSOData service I have an entity based on calculation view with input parameters. I can to set these parameters as constants in my XML view, i.e.

```
<List items="{dicts>/AncParams(p_dict_name='GROUPS',p_rec_id=2)/Results}" >
        <StandardListItem
          title="{dicts>NAME}"
          />
    </List>
```

and it will work fine.

But how I can set parameters `p_dict_name` and `p_rec_id` dynamically? I tried to use expression bindings to get values for parameters from another model (something like this: `<List items="{= ${dicts>/AncParams(p_dict_name='GROUPS',p_rec_id=${DictUIProps>/parentId})/Results} }" >`) but with no luck. As I understand, expression bindings won't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: I think thats the way. Read it, store these values (as a total list) and apply the filter via java script. Means expression binding on the list via a local model is correct, but without these filtering in the expression. will be difficult with an expression, but anyway it should be possibe https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_pobuilder10/1.0.05/de-DE/da/f6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0/content.htm?no_cache=true

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you can't do the aggregation binding dynamically through XML. At least not in the versions I have used and I have to admit I haven't re-checked in a while. The string never gets interpreted for inner bindings before it's applied to the model.

The way I do this is through the controller:

```
<List id="myList" />
```

and in your controller (`onBeforeRendering` or `onPatternMatched` or wherever your model and view are known to the controller):

```
this.getView().byId('myList').bindItems({
  model: 'dicts',
  path: `{/AncParams(p_dict_name='${p_dict_name}',p_rec_id=${p_rec_id})/Results}`,
  template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    title: '{dicts>NAME}'
  })
});
```

you can use the `getModel('dicts').createKey` function to generate the path name which is a little cleaner I suppose.

This is the way to apply dynamic filters as well, In case you ever build those.

Comment: My used version is 1.28.
Well, I wrote this code just for test purposes, in fact I want to use this approach in my custom control (it will have `items` aggregation too). Is it true, that I should redefine `onBeforeRendering` in my custom control and bind `items` aggregation in this method like in your code snippet?

Comment: In a custom control I do things generally in the onBeforeRendering method too, yes, but it depends a little what are you trying to make. Are you extending the list and providing a dict_name parameter?

Comment: I want to make breadcrumbs with some augments. In item I need a link + icon, so it will be a `BreadcrumbItem` extends a `sap.m.Link`. For container I plan to create `Breadcrumb` which extends a `Control` and contains `items` aggregation and `root` aggregation.